# How to find out erroneous values in one column based on values in another column in R?

Tags: r

I have two columns of data (say `id` and `master_id`) in R. It should be the case that all the values in `id` should be present in `master_id`. But, I suspect that is not the case and I want to identify which ones are the erroneous values. I cannot just inspect the data as I am dealing with data of the order of 100k.

How do I go about finding the erroneous values?

Comment: If you are looking for different values in two columns you can use `setdiff(id, master_id)`. It will return the values of `id` which are not in `master_id`

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [one of the top R questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right/1300618#1300618).  See also: ?merge

Comment: See comment above.  Also the question does not include [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also the question does not include what you have already tried.  Also the question does not include what you have already searched.

Answer (score 1):

the %in% function may come in handy. It will throw an FALSE for those cases that are in the first but not the second set

E.g.

```
DF$master_id %in% DF$id
```

id is the subset of master_id, so master_id values without a counterpart will get a FALSE

or, to see how it works run (from R help file)

```
1:10 %in% c(1,3,5,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933190/subtracting-two-data-frames/16939696#16939696) from 2 days ago:

```
library(data.table)
DF1<-data.frame(x=1:3,y=4:6,t=10:12)
DF2<-data.frame(x=3:5,y=6:8,s=1:3)
library(data.table)
DF1 <- data.table(DF1, key = c("x", "y"))
DF2 <- data.table(DF2, key = c("x", "y"))
DF1[!DF2] # maybe you want this?
DF2[!DF1] # or maybe you want this?
```